# Go to the next forEach iteration after promise resolves

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm going throgh the array of some data and on every iteration I deal with promise.

What I want is to go to the next `forEach` iteration only when the promise on the current iteration is resolved.

I searched through out different solutions and figured out that usage of `for(... of ...)` instead of `forEach` could make the trick. But still can't figure it out.

```
const data = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];

data.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
  let params = {
    fruitIndex: rowIndex,
  };

  axios.post('/fruits', { ...params })
    .then(response => {
      // go to the next iteration of forEach only after this promise resolves
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
});
```

Comment: Never make api calls inside of a loop

Comment: Do you have async/await support?

Comment: @Ry- yes, I do have it

Comment: Although it's not recommended making the API call synchronous should work for your use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion helps:

```js
const data = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];


function request_fruit(n) {
  let params = {
    fruitIndex: n,
  };

  axios.post('/fruits', { ...params })
    .then(response => {
      // Work with recived...
      // ....
      // Request next
      if(n+1<fruits.length) request_fruit(n+1)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
};
request_fruit(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can, i'd recommed an easy to read and understand for of loop with await/async. Notice the top level await is very recent addition, so you should wrap that in some async function (which you'd likely do anyway).

If you cannot use async/await you can use `reduce` with an initial resolved promise to chain subsequent calls.

**Notice** that I used a function `sleep` that resolves a promise after some time. The call to `sleep` should be interchangeable with axios calls.

```js
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const data = [1000, 2000, 3000];


function withReduce() {
  console.log('Sequential Promises with Reduce:');

  return data.reduce((previousPromise, ms) => {
    return previousPromise
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`sleeping for ${ms}ms`);
        return sleep(ms);
      });
  }, Promise.resolve());
}

async function withAsync() {
  console.log('Sequential Promises with for of and await:');

  for (let ms of data) {
    console.log(`sleeping for ${ms}ms`);
    await sleep(ms);
  }
}

withReduce().then(withAsync);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like nobody posted the specific async/await yet, so this is how you use it with for…of:

```
const data = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];

for (const [rowIndex, row] of data.entries()) {
  let params = {
    fruitIndex: rowIndex,
  };

  let response;

  try {
    response = await axios.post('/fruits', { ...params });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    continue;
  }

  // …
}
```

This all being placed inside an async function. (Also, `{ ...params }` is a bit weird. What’s wrong with `params` directly?)

Comment: Params indeed looks weird, thank you for this remark!

Answer (score -1):

Just use await on the api call.

```js
function postFruitData(){
    const data = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];

    data.forEach(async (row, rowIndex) => {
      let params = {
        fruitIndex: rowIndex,
      };

      const response = await axios.post('/fruits', { ...params })
    });
}
```

Comment: @Sergey Gubarev [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/asynchronous-javascript-using-async-await) is a good tutorial on async/await if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But where is async keyword in your code example? I think it is required when await is using.

Comment: @SergeyGubarev yes, you are right, I thougt I was explicit enougth. Check my update please.

Comment: This still won’t work as written. `await` is inside a non-async function inside the async function.

Comment: @Ry- Thank you, I miss the place of the async. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @SergeyGubarev If you still need this please check the update.

Comment: This isn’t serial. async functions don’t work in `forEach`, to put it simply.

Comment: @RicardoAraújo I tried solution with recursive function. It's not as modern as async/await, but it works. Async/await solution seems bit complicated in my case. Thank you guys for helping me!